# jquery selectable and right click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a jquery selectable as shown below.

```
//Selectable Functionality
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#Selectable_Positions").selectable({
        selected: function (event, ui) {
            dostuff();
        }
    })
})
```

It is working correctly however only left click will cause the select event to fire. I am trying to make it so that right click will as well. I have tried adding the code below and the alert fires but the selected item does not change.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#Selectable_Positions').mousedown(function () {
        $('#Selectable_Positions').trigger('selectableselected');
        alert('foo');
    })
})
```

How can I programatically change the selected item in the mousedown event function?

---

**edit**

Updated eventname as per Ian's suggestion below.

I have created a jsfiddle showing what I am trying to achieve and the triggered event not firing on right click. Does anybody know how to make this work? It would be greatly appreciated

http://jsfiddle.net/Jzjdm/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ended up writing my own select function and calling it on right click. Not sure what is up with that event.

Answer (score 2):

The correct **event name** is "selectableselected". So use:

```
$('#Selectable_Positions').trigger('selectableselected');
```

Reference:

- http://api.jqueryui.com/selectable/#event-selected

Comment: That seems like it would work but it doesn't seem to. I am getting the same thing... very unsure why.

Comment: @Jamesla Hmm you're right, sorry for the confusion. This way normally works with jQuery UI widget events. I've been trying many different combinations of code to get it to trigger it but it won't seem to happen. I won't lie, I don't know how I missed your original question was about right clicking, but that's not entirely relevant (because I can't manually trigger it from anywhere). At the same time, it kind of makes sense, because you need to trigger it for a specific element, not just on the container. I was thinking to trigger a `click` event on the specific `<li>`